# Update boostrap input externally with jQuery isn't showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've tried:

```
 $(element).attr("value", newValue);
```

which changed the value when I inspect the element but it doesn't show when I look at the actual input. I've then tried to .trigger different stuff but it doesn't work. (I've also tried $(element).val(newValue)).

EDIT: Found the error, I imported an obj from the server in JSON format. When I parsed it, the property I wanted to use didn't work as expected in the val function. Only sometimes it worked. To fix it I, when parsing it, used eval() on the object property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jQuery's [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method:

`$(element).val(newValue);`

Bootstrap should not be making any difference here.

Always check what you are passing to the `val()` (or any other) function and what that function expects as parameter, especially when using a specific unit or doing some calculations which might end up being string concatenations instead.

```js
jQuery("input").val(456);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="input"></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="elementID" placeholder="..." value="123">
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not see that. Could you show your JS code? I have no problems getting or setting the value of an `input` element.

Comment: That's strange, well the only thing different is that I've got an class="input-group-addon" (span after it) aswell

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" id="value1" placeholder="Värde" value="newValue"> When I look at it in the console I see this, it just doesn't show up

Comment: What is `element` in your code exactly? I guess you access the wrong element or your selector does not match any element at all.

Comment: It does match and I can see the element change value in the console element inspector, but It doesn't show in the actual input. When I check your code it does the reverse, in the inspector it's still 123 while it shows 456.

Comment: Ok, please provide a (not) working snippet in your question. Are you listening for some events that trigger a change? These might be „off“.

Comment: I did some tests, and f I added a normal value into val like val(320) it worked if I only had my variable in val like val(x) it didnt work, if I put val("320" + x) I get 320 and my value. Very weird.

Comment: Couldn't provide a snippet, seems to be some problem with the variable, I can log it and see it is a normal number but when I put it as val it doesn't work. If I put some arbitrary number like 320 it does work.

Comment: I found out the error, you can see in the answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ok, great. I edited my answer to reflect the root cause of your problem. You might want to accept it (you should)... or you don't. :)